# MS Access VBA - Download an XML file from stored procedure output

Tags: xml, ms-access, stored-procedures, vba

I need to have a function that downloads an XML file from a stored procedure and saves it to the disk. Is this possible with MS Access VBA?

Here's my test sample in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestXML](
[ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[PID] [int] NULL,
[Code] [int] NULL,
[Col1] [int] NULL,
[Col2] [int] NULL,
[Col3] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
[Col4] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
[Col5] [int] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_TestXML] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
)

GO
INSERT [dbo].[TestXML] ([ID], [PID], [Code], [Col1], [Col2], [Col3], [Col4], [Col5]) VALUES (1, 1000, 10, 1, 2, CAST(0.20 AS Decimal(6, 2)), CAST(0.10 AS Decimal(6, 2)), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[TestXML] ([ID], [PID], [Code], [Col1], [Col2], [Col3], [Col4], [Col5]) VALUES (2, 1000, 20, NULL, 1, CAST(1.00 AS Decimal(6, 2)), CAST(1.00 AS Decimal(6, 2)), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[TestXML] ([ID], [PID], [Code], [Col1], [Col2], [Col3], [Col4], [Col5]) VALUES (3, 1000, 30, NULL, NULL, CAST(2.00 AS Decimal(6, 2)), CAST(2.00 AS Decimal(6, 2)), 5)
GO
```

Sproc

```
CREATE PROCEDURE returnXML 
(@ID int,
 @xmlOut XML OUTPUT)

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT @xmlOut=(SELECT PID [p/@v],(
    SELECT Code as [code/@c], Col1 AS [code/val]
    FROM [dbo].[TestXML]
    WHERE ID=@ID
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
  FROM [dbo].[TestXML]
  WHERE ID=@ID
  FOR XML PATH('u'),TYPE)

END
GO
```

VBA (what I tried to do, but I don't know what to use for XML variables)

```
Function getXML(sproc As String, id As Integer) As Object
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim cnnStr As String
    Dim Rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim StrSproc As String

    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    Set Rs = New ADODB.Recordset


    cnnStr = getConnString()

    With cnn
        .CommandTimeout = 900
        .ConnectionString = cnnStr
        .Open
    End With
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = cnn
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = sproc
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@ID", adInteger, adParamInput, id)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@xmlOut", adLongVarChar, adParamOutput)

    End With
    With Rs
        .CursorType = adOpenStatic
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .LockType = adLockOptimistic
        .Open cmd
    End With
    Set rst = cmd.Execute(, , adCmdStoredProc)
    getXML = cmd.Parameters("@xmlOut").Value

End Function
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Should be possible. Where are you stuck?

Comment: For start to the xml parameter type. The ones I tried (adVarBinary, adLongVarChar) are giving the following error "Parameter object is improperly defined.Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided"

Comment: I would have a look here https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=295789&highlight=json for an extensive discussion about JSON and access parsing.

Comment: If you are interested, you can have a look at my [GitHub JsonExporter](https://github.com/krishKM/VBA_TOOLS/blob/master/README.md#exporttojson) which can export queries/tables as JSON string.

Answer (score 3):

Do you really have to use a T-SQL return parameter?

In general the return parameters of a stored procedure are best if you writing “other” T-SQL routines and want a value returned back.

For general code, why not just execute a select and return the value as a table, select like what is done in most cases?

So in place of

```
Select @MyXml = (blab la bla)
```

Just go

```
select (blab la bla).
```

Or at the end, simple declare @MyXml as a var, and go

```
Select @MyXml
```

If you take the above road, then your stored procedure becomes:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE returnXML 
    (@ID INT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT (SELECT PID [p/@v],(
    SELECT Code as [code/@c], Col1 AS [code/val]
    FROM [dbo].[TestXML]
    WHERE ID=@ID
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
FROM [dbo].[TestXML]
WHERE ID=@ID
FOR XML PATH('u'),TYPE)
END
GO
```

And in Access, if you have a pass-though query declared (you should have one for “general use”, then you can go:

```
Sub Test1()

   Dim i        As Integer
   Dim strXML   As String

   i = InputBox("What id")
       With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryPassR")
      .SQL = "returnXML " & i
      strXML = .OpenRecordset()(0)
   End With

   Debug.Print strXML
```

And using a pt query in Access means you don’t mess with connection strings in code.

So unless some "big" reason exists to have that return parameter, then you can use the above. And if you really must use some "existing" t-sql routine that returns a value, then I would suggest using a exec + a select @MyXml.

So even if you are forced to use the return value, you in the above .SQL = go something like:

```
declare @MyXML varcharmx
Myxml 1,@Mxml;select @myxml
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The problem with returning the selection as a string is that I loose the XML formatting which I need, that's why I thought of returning the XML variable.

Comment: Hum, I see xml as a string being returned - not sure why you seeing different. About the only issue might be xml length more then 255, but other then that, the string returned should retain the xml formatting.

Comment: It's more that 255,but you are right, if it's less that 255 then it keeps the formatting.